# Retrieving admin rights/ admin information on a session

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Im currently trying to retrieve information on a current session and I would like to see if this current session has admin rights.

My plan was to Enumerate all sessions using `WTSEnumerateSessions` and then loop over each session and call `WTSQuerySessionInformation` and pass `WTSSessionInfo` as the parameter. However I realised the struct for this is `_WTS_SESSION_INFO_1` and there is no information regarding if this session has admin rights.

So i was wondering if this is possible?

Comment: What does it mean for a session to have admin rights. Different processes within the session have different rights. You need to first of all work out what the information you need actually is. If we are to help you work out the solution then it would help to know what the problem is. What decisions are you going to take based on this information?

Comment: Privileges on Windows are more fine-grained than *is admin* and *is not admin*. What are you trying to achieve? Why not query for the privileges instead?

Comment: If you're running as local system, you could use WTSQueryUserToken and examine the TokenElevationType of the token returned.